# How to prevent user interaction with invisible forms?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

In my application there appeared a following problem: certain dialogue forms can be interacted with before they are drawn.

The code goes like:

```
void FunctionCalledFromButtonPressHandler()
{
    var f = new MyDialog();
    if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
    //do things
    }
}
```

The buttons on the starting form and dialog form (one that loses it) are over each other on the touchscreen. If the plac is clicked over twice, there is a pause corresponding to the load of dialog form, and then, without it being shown, wotk in starting form is continued/

How should i go about preventing such sort of behaviour (that is, apart from removing the delay on the loading of dialog)?

Comment: If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you could just set the Enabled property of the button to 'false' until it's ready to be interacted with, if you don't want to change anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Set 'Button.Enabled = false;' on your starting form inside the launching method.

```
void FunctionCalledFromButtonPressHandler()
{
    YOURBUTTON.Enabled = false;
    var f = new MyDialog();
    if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
    //do things
    }
    YOURBUTTON.Enabled = true;
}
```

Then in your dialog form set the other `Button.Enabled = false;` in the form constructor.  Then you can set the button to enabled in the `Shown` event like this:

```
void MyDialog_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OTHERBUTTON.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this. However, Shown event never occurs. May have something to do withmobile .net being somewhat cut down.